# I'm getting a 404 error when trying to render my results for my API Hack assignment

Tags: json, api, http-status-code-404

I'm working on an API Hack assignment for my class with Thinkful and my issue has been that I've been trying to make a call to spoonacular's food api and render the results onto the DOM. However, when I try to do that, All I get in return is a 404 error. I'm wondering if i did something wrong or is some unforeseen problem that is beyond my control?

I've already look at manually typing the composed URL and postman as well.

```
function queryParams(params) {
    const queryItems = Object.keys(params).map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}= ${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`)
    return queryItems.join('&');
}


function displayResults(responseJson){
  console.log(responseJson);
  $('#results-list').empty();
  for(let i = 0; i < responseJson.results.length; i++){
    $('#results-list').append(
      `<li><h3><a href="${responseJson.results[i].title}">${responseJson.results[i].id},${responseJson.results[i].protein}</a></h3>
      <p>By ${responseJson.results[i].calories}</p>
      <img src='${responseJson.results[i].image}'>
      </li>`
    )};

   $('#results').removeClass('hidden');

};
```

```
function getRecipe(query,maxResults,){
  const params ={
    q:query,
    number: maxResults,
  };


  const queryString = queryParams(params)
  const url = searchUrl+'?'+ queryString +'?apiKey='+ apikey;

  console.log(url);
```

```
fetch(url,option)
  .then(response =>{
    if(response.ok){
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  })
  .then(response => console.log(responseJson))
  .catch(err =>{
    $('#js-error-message').text(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`);
  });
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchRecipe = $('.js-search-recipe').val();
    const maxResults = $('.js-max-results').val();
    getRecipe(searchRecipe, maxResults);
  });
}

$(watchForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a couple issues:

First, you're constructing an invalid url:

`const url = searchUrl+'?'+ queryString +'?apiKey='+ apikey;`

notice the 2 `?`s

Also, when you're constructing the query params, you're adding a space between the `=` and the value of your param

`${encodeURIComponent(key)}= ${encodeURIComponent(params[key])}`

If you're using the correct path and a valid API key, fixing those things may be enough to make it work.